# How to display 2 prices in different currencies for an item inVirtuemar

Tags: virtuemart

I need to show 2 prices in different currencies on a flypage, but I haven't found a recipe for it so far. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this by adding a new input field.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, needs a little coding...

1 - Edit the file default_showprices.php in template folder (**/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default_showprices.php**)

2 - Get the currency_id ( from virtuemart admin ). For example, I use the US$ currency ID: 144.

3 - Place this code bellow in any line of the file:

```
echo '<b>US$: '.$this->currency->roundForDisplay($this->product->prices['salesPrice'],144,1,false).'</b>';
```

This code will print the price converted to US$.